# NSDateComponentsFormatter NSString to NSTimeInterval

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nstimeinterval

I hope I didn't miss anything but from reading the documentation I get:

`NSDateComponentsFormatter` provides a method `- (NSString * nullable)stringFromTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)ti` which can be used to convert an NSTimeInterval into an NSString. 
However I couldn't find any method that that converts the resulting string back into an NSTimeInterval.

Is their anything like an equivalent to `NSDateFormatter` `- (NSDate *)dateFromString:(NSString *)string` ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`NSTimeInterval` is simply a `double` value, so just get the `doubleValue` of the string.

```
NSTimeInterval ti = [yourString doubleValue];
```

---

**EDIT:** Per your comments, you are correct- I was making an assumption that the value returned by `stringFromTimeInterval:` was an unformatted double value. Based off some quick observations, there does not seem to be a simple way to convert the string back to a double value, regardless of the `unitsStyle` used in the `NSDateComponentsFormatter`, as none of the styles provide an easily-parseable format. I assume you would need to write your own method to search through the resulting string for ranges of substrings and do the math yourself.

Comment: NSDateComponentsFormatter formates the time interval to somthing like "1m 10s". So simple getting the double value of the string won't work...